# How to get text from a specific line in Batch

Tags: batch-file

I'd like to write a batch script that reads a specific word between delimiters:

Eg my text file contains the below

```
!DATA
Scen|2022|m|YTD|a|b|c|d|e|f|g|h|101
Scen|2022|m|YTD|a1|b1|c1|d1|e1|f1|g1|h1|102
```

The text file will have around 1000 lines. I will always want to read the 3rd line.

I want to:

**1.** Get the first word before the pipe delimiter (eg `Scen`) and store to some variable

**2.** I then want the second word between 1st & 2nd pipe marks (eg `2022`)

Any help in this would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example for you to really get your teeth into:

```bash
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
Set "targetLine="
(   Set /P "="
    Set /P "="
    Set /P "targetLine="
) 0< "textFile.ext"
If Not Defined targetLine GoTo :EOF
For /F "Delims==" %%G In ('"(Set Field) 2>NUL"') Do Set "%%G="
Set "i=1"
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Set "Field!i!=%targetLine:|=" & Set /A i +=1 & Set "Field!i!=%"
Echo %%Field1%% = %Field1%; %%Field2%% = %Field2%
Pause
```

The above technique has actually defined a variable for each of the pipe delimited fields. To see those just change line `13` to `(Set Field) 2>NUL`

`(Set /P "var=") 0< "stdInput"` defines `var` with the value of the first non empty input line, In this case you would change `stdInput` *(`textfile.ext`)* to your actual source file. I have therefore extended the idea to retrieve the third line. I will not explain the creation of the variables for each of the fields, simply link you to [an already existing explanation](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6429).

Answer (score 0):

- If these are your intended executions:

```sh
!DATA                                       // Your Line Skipped: 1
Scen|2022|m|YTD|a|b|c|d|e|f|g|h|101         // Your Line Skipped: 2
Scen|2022|m|YTD|a1|b1|c1|d1|e1|f1|g1|h1|102 // Your Line Strings To Save: Scen & 2022
...                                         // Your Lines Remaining Skipped: Goto %:^)
```

---

- A simpler way to do it would be:

```sh
@echo off & cd /d "%~dp0"

for /f "usebackq skip=2 delims=| tokens=1-2*" %%i in (`
    type InputFile.txt`)do set "_str_1=%%i" && set "_str_2=%%j" & goto %:^)

%:^)
echo\ %%_str_1%% == %_str_1% && echo\ %%_str_2%% == %_str_2%
```

Answer (score 0):

Another, perhaps simpler, method:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Read the 3rd line
( for /L %%i in (1,1,3) do set /P "line3=" ) < test.txt

rem Get 1st and 2nd words from line 3
set "goto="
set "word1=%line3:|=" & !goto! & set "goto=goto continue" & set "word2=%"
:continue

echo word1="%word1%", word2="%word2%"
```